# Publish and Deploy Asp.net MVC with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Recently, I have used Asp.net MVC with AngularJS to create a web application. When running code, the apps running without any problems and error in code. However, after I published and deployed it in Server, the delete and search function cannot work as expected. May I know what is the normal causes for this kind of problems? Need I configure the server to allow CRUD operations?

Wong

Comment: The publish is a different concept and the CRUD operation is different!

Comment: Can you explain more about this? I published the web app and then deployed it in Server. CRUD operation in C# code-behind, that already compiled into DLL together with the aspx pages.

Comment: On which server? Is it windows *IIS* or Azure?

Comment: Window Server 2012. Really amazing , delete operation no error when running code. But after published and deployed, delete operation failed when hosting it in server.

Comment: are you publishing your website on IIS Server?

Comment: Yes, after published, deploying it in IIS Server. Any idea to solve it?

Comment: Your MVC app and angular should be inside one site or under one domain.

Comment: And for delete and put verb you can google not exactly know what it is but have to modify web.config file

Comment: I have tried this way, also cannot ~~